# Trying to run c++ file but it is saying the launch.json needs to have its include path updated

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Trying to run a simple hello world program in C++  that looks like this

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

However, it is giving me the error: #include errors detected. Please update your `includePath`. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit

I went to the Json file it directed me to and I am displayed this

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "cl",
            "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/path/to/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am confused on what to do next, if anyone could help, it would be greatly be appreciated

Comment: The configuration file looks confused. What compiler are you actually using?

Comment: BTW we get more questions about VS Code than any other IDE. It's seems to be very hard for beginners to set up successfully. My advice would be to pick a different IDE if you can.

Comment: I will  recommend you to use the integrated terminal in VScode to run c++ program.

Comment: @john I also suspect that nobody reads the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

Comment: Consider using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org) (as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) (as `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) on the command line

Answer (score 0):

Find where your gdb.exe file is located and enter it in the "miDebuggerPath".

Mine is:

```
  "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
```